# php consume data from another authorized website

Tags: php, web-services, soap

what can be the best method to consume data from 1 site to another site using php.

Site A is classified site listing ads (cars, animals, bikes etc).

Site B is another classified site that also list ads, Site B wants to show its ads on site A.

I know there should be 2 implementation 1 on Site A (data consumer), and another on site B (data generator).

Site B should has an account on site A, and should provide username and password, to be consumed data on site A

I am considering SOAP. Any better suggestion...

Comment: Why not use a restful service?

Comment: @mserioli : explain a bit, let me know restfull services that i can use.

Comment: Take a look here http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/ and here http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/making-restful-requests-in-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you own both sites you should look into creating some sort of an API that can be called from other locations.  Web services are very helpful and SOAP is a great way to go.  The other method would be to allow access to your database from remote locations and then open a connection from Site B to Site A when needed.  This does offer up a few security concerns though and may be a bit sluggish depending on where the servers are in relationship to one another geographically.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to make Rest Api for your application.